# Default value for template with member function pointer

Tags: c++, templates, pointer-to-member

So, I have something like this so far:

```
struct Foo { int DoNothing() { } };

template<typename T, typename C, typename R>
T Func(C const* obj,
       R (C::*mf)(),
       T* maybe_unused = nullptr)
{
    (obj->*mf)();
    return T{};
}

Foo f;
int r = Func<int>(&f, &Foo::DoNothing); // works as expected
```

How do I make `&Foo::DoNothing()` the default for `Func(...)`?
IOW, I would like to pass some other member function of `Foo`
at another time but for the most part, I want `DoNothing` to
be the default. We can safely assume all the member functions
I am interested in take no arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I make `&Foo::DoNothing()` the default for `Func(...)`?

You basically just specify the required default arguments:

```
struct Foo { int DoNothing() const { } };

template<
  typename T, 
  typename C, 
  typename R = decltype(std::declval<const C>().DoNothing())
>
T Func(C const* obj,
       R (C::*mf)() const = &C::DoNothing,
       T* maybe_unused = nullptr)
{
    (obj->*mf)();
    return T{};
}
```

Note that you need to specify two different things: for one the default member function to call and additionally the default return value type, as it cannot be deduced from default arguments.

Comment: That is not the problem.

Comment: @ForeverLearning the only error is that Foo f is not const. Otherwise it is fine.

Comment: In *my* opinion, there is NONE! This rocks. Thanks Jodocus. I did know about `declval` and `decltype` but never thought of putting them together like you have!

Comment: During testing I found that if you change C to not be const keyword it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Change Func to:

```
template<typename T, typename R, typename C>
T Func(C const* obj, R (C::*mf)()=&C::do_nothing, T* maybe_unused = nullptr)
{
...
}
```

Note that because obj is const I actually had to change it to:

```
template<typename T, typename R, typename C>
T Func(C const* obj, R (C::*mf)() const=&C::do_nothing, T* maybe_unused = nullptr)
{
...
}
```

and I changed do_nothing() to be const as well.